# How to enabled up/down keys in a JavaFX Spinner component

Tags: java, spinner, javafx-8

I'm using a Spinner component in my JavaFX application. It's created via FXML:

```xml
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" editable="true" min="0" max="100"
         initialValue="3" />
```

According to the documentation of [Spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html):

> The keyboard up/down arrow keys also cycle through the elements.

However, when I click in the spinner component and press UP or DOWN only the cursor position in the text field changes but not the spinner value.

Is it possible to let the spinner component react on UP and DOWN as described in the JavaDoc?

I already tried to add a key listener to do this job:

```java
spinner.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    switch (event.getCode()) {
        case UP:
            spinner.increment(1);
            break;
        case DOWN:
            spinner.decrement(1);
            break;
    }
});
```

However, this listener is only called when I press UP or DOWN in combination with the control key, which is not very intuitive.  Is there a solution without such a key combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is because you have `editable="true"` in your FXML. TextField in spinner will become editable and intercept all clicks, so you just need to set Listener on editorProperty()  and not spinner itself. Something like this:

```
spinner.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    System.out.println("++1");
                    spinner.increment(1);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    System.out.println("--1");
                    spinner.decrement(1);
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you want `setOnKeyPressed` and not `setOnKeyTyped`. The latter does not trigger when arrow keys are pressed.